# Physics Problem about a Child on a Water Slide Getting Launched into the air

Tags: homework-and-exercises

[image]

I don't have any idea how I would go about solving this problem.

Comment: Use conservation of energy

Comment: Which equation for conservation of energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use the conservation of mechanical Energy to find the kinetic energy of the child just before leaving the edge of the slide. The magnitude of the velocity can be found using the kinetic energy and the direction id already given in the form of an angle. Now, resolve the velocity into a vertical and a horizontal component. The horizontal component is of no importance here; use the vertical component of velocity and the equations of motion under uniform acceleration to find the maximum height obtained.